# Handling null values for C# linq where query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to retrieve information from various tables through join, however when one table has a null value and the where query is implemented it causes the entire query to return null

```
var query =   from mUser in userQuery  
              join mContactAddress in //table 
              on mUser.ID equals mContactAddress.ContactID into fullmContactAddress
              from mContactAddress in fullmContactAddress.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { mUser, mContactAddress } into mUserContactAddress

              let stateID = (mUserContactAddress.id != null)? mUser.ContactAddress.id : null

              join stateName in //table
                on stateID  equals stateName.ID into masterTranslateSet
                from stateName in masterTranslateSet.DefaultIfEmpty(new TMasterTranslate {
                    PropertyID = 3,
                    Value = null
                })
               where stateName.PropertyID == 3
                select new UserInfo() {
                    stateId = stateID,
                    address = mUserContactAddress.mContactAddress, 
                    stateName = stateName.Value,

                });
```

It works properly when everything is populated however if stateID is null the `where` clause causes an issue and query becomes a null object. I want everything to be populated but have `query.stateName == null` instead of the entire object being null.

It works properly when the where clause is commented out.

Comment: It returns as null when I run the code. Can you elaborate

Comment: By "causes an issue" do you mean "throws an exception"?

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception but it causes the `query` to equal null. When I remove the where line the query is correctly populated

Comment: What is `userQuery`? Or, what type of LINQ / ORM is this, and which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using a where clause it will go through the entire query and will then return null for the entire operation. to avoid this, join the objects on the values you are looking for.

```
let stateID = (mUserContactAddress.id != null)? mUser.ContactAddress.id : -1 //invalid id if null
join stateName in //table
on new { stateId = stateID, PropertyID = 30 } equals new { stateId = stateName.ID, PropertyID = stateName.PropertyID } into masterTranslateSet
from stateName in masterTranslateSet.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `stateName.Value` with `stateName?.Value`.  The question mark is probably in the sample code you are trying to use, but you missed it.

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to do that it causes a compile issue saying that `an expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator`. I tried just returning a random string in it's place but the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If stateId is null then the join will fail, which would mean stateName is null, which would cause the where to be false.

Maybe you could change to:

```
where (stateId == null OR stateName.PropertyID == 3 )
```

Comment: when I put in `OR` it showed a compiler error so I put in `||` instead and when I ran it the following error occured: `System.NotSupportedException: 'The expression 'IIF(([mAddress].ID != ), [mAddress].StateID, )' (type: System.Linq.Expressions.ConditionalExpression) is not supported by the TOF LINQ provider.'`